# Excel - that function isn't valid - how to get rid of it?

Tags: excel, error-handling, macros, formulas

In excel I am creating a report with a list of all stored procedures that I have altered, and sometimes I have changed also the parameter types.

I have created a procedure that gives me the list of parameters of a procedure and their data types.

for example:

```
exec sp_GetSPtables  'dbo.udpProductBulletPointSelectByTier1NoteTypeCode'
```

gives me `Parameters:`

> @Tier1 VARCHAR(10),@LanguageID INT,@SeasonItemID
>   VARCHAR(5),@ListNoteTypeCode VARCHAR(MAX),@CacheDuration INT OUTPUT

when I try to paste the parameters above into Excel though, I get the following error:

[image]

How can I disable this behaviour from excel?

Comment: @pnuts that worked fine, problem solved, thanks

Comment: @pnuts good tip it helped me to, if you write as a answer it can be marked as answered. I agree this is very superuser related (I almost voted to close / migrate), but I suppose because it's the "@" in a stored procedure it could come in useful for this community.

Comment: Where has the answer gone to?